# Filepicker - Modals opens on page load

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

I'm integrating Filepicker into a form on a web page. Everything is working fine but I cannot stop the modal from opening by itself on each page load. I can't find a way of disabling this.

Here's the set up I'm playing with at the moment:

```
<script>
    // Set up the API key
    filepicker.setKey("XXXXXXX");

    filepicker.pickAndStore(
        // picker_options
        {
            openTo: 'COMPUTER',
            services: ['CLOUDDRIVE','COMPUTER','DROPBOX','FACEBOOK','GITHUB','GOOGLE_DRIVE','GMAIL','SKYDRIVE','URL','FTP','CLOUDAPP'],
            maxSize: 20971520,
        },
        // store_options
        {

        },
        function(Blobs){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(Blobs));
        },
        function(error){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        },
        function(progress){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(progress));
        }
    );
</script>
```

Same thing happens on codepen so it's nothing in the rest of the page that causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're picking a file, you should have the action of the pickAndStore function within the function called when you click a button to activate it.

```
var button = document.getElementById('filePick');
button.onclick(function() {
    filepicker.pickAndStore({
        //etc.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, obvious really! I just converted it to jQuery as I use it already on the page. All works fine now.